# Groupby Object in Pandas to Seaborn Plot: Is there an easy way?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

This has been a recurring theme in my struggle with Pandas and *the* reason why I've been reluctant to make the switch from R.

Take this small data set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
iris_data = sns.load_dataset('iris')
df = iris_data.head(5).copy()
df = pd.concat([df, iris_data.iloc[50:55]])
df = pd.concat([df, iris_data.iloc[100:105]])
df
```

When I run the following commands, I get a nice groupby object, followed by an error:

```
x = df.groupby('species')['sepal_length', 'sepal_width'].sum()
```

[image: groupby object]

```
sns.barplot(x='species', y='sepal_length', data=x)
```

Why? Because groupby robs you of your columns/variable names and turns everything into an unreadable index and Seaborn can't read them. I see the row/column labels, but it doesn't. I've tried unstacking, reset_index, adding dummy columns (no one should have to do this), and still I cannot find a simple solution to this issue. All I want is for the data in my groupby object to be easily transferrable to a plot in sns or plotnine. I've wasted too much time on this. I'd be grateful for some insight here.

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't supplied a sample to reproduce the dataframe I can't be sure if this will work for you, but I do think its what you're looking for as far as resetting the dataframe index:

```
x = df.groupby('species')[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width']].sum().reset_index(level=[0])
```

Comment: you can also just ```df.groupby('species').sum().reset_index() ; sns.barplot(x='species', y='sepal_length', data=x)``` ? Just asking, it should give the same plot